# Algebra help. Parallel impedances.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[Circuit in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fBRt.jpg)

Hi, i'm going through some homework solutions to study but can't algebraically understand how $$Za(iw) =  \frac{3}{5}(1-2i)$$

In general, to find $Z_{eq}$ when $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are parallel the formula should be $$Z_{eq} = \frac{Z_1(Z_2)}{Z_1 + Z_2}$$ My attempt given that $Z_1 = -i \frac{3}{2}$ and $Z_2 = 3$  $$Z_a{} = \frac{-i \frac{3}{2}(3)}{-i \frac{3}{2} + 3}$$ $$Z_a{} = \frac{-i \frac{9}{2}}{-i \frac{3}{2} + \frac{6}{2}}$$
$$Z_a{} = \frac{-i 9}{-i 3 + 6}$$ factor out -3 to get $$Z_a{} = \frac{i 3}{i  - 2}$$ mind pointing me to the right direction?

Comment: What was the question again?

Comment: The solution is showing that $Za(iw) =  \frac{3}{5}(1-2i)$ but when I try to simplify it I get $Z_a{} = \frac{i 3}{i  - 2}$. So my question is how did they get to $Za(iw) =  \frac{3}{5}(1-2i)$. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Good, ok, you can multiply both numerator and denominator with the same value and the fraction will remain the same. Is there some value you can multiply i-2 to make it become real?

Comment: The conjugate! Thanks, that completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to multiply top and bottom by the conjugate